# Function composition and type annotations in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Total noob here. I've seen an example of doing HTTP Get request using `do` block, but I want to do it via composition.

Like this:

```
get url = getResponseBody . simpleHTTP $ getRequest url
```

Is it proper? And what is the right type annotation for this function?

This one is ok:

```
get :: String -> IO String
get url = getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest url)
```

But I want to compose and not to bind. What it a better/right way?

Comment: Can you provide the types for `getResponseBody`, `simpleHTTP`, and `getRequest`?  Or at least the module(s) they come from?

Comment: They comes from Network.HTTP

Comment: What's wrong with the bind? `=<<` _is_, in a sense, composition for monadic functions (aka Kleisli arrows). More precisely, `<=<` is the Kleisli composition operator: `get = getResponseBody <=< simpleHTTP . getRequest`.

Comment: Nothing wrong, I'm just wondering how to do it differently and what option is right. What s the difference between bind and compose then?

Comment: Composition is between two functions (of compatible types). Application is between a function of type `a->b` and an argument of type `a`. Bind is similar to application in that it "applies" a function of type `a -> m b` to an argument of type `m a`, where `m` is a monad. Note that regular application would complain that the function expects an `a`, not an `m a`. Further, application is a fixed operation, while every monad `m` has its own bind operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the types:

```
getRequest :: String -> Request_String
simpleHTTP :: Request ty -> IO (Result (Response ty))
getResponseBody :: Result (Response ty) -> IO ty
type Request_String = Request String
```

So for the purposes of this question we can specialize the types to

```
simpleHTTP :: Request_String -> IO (Result (Response String))
getResponseBody :: Result (Response String) -> IO String
```

It's pretty clear to see that we can just do

```
simpleHTTP (getRequest url) :: IO (Result (Response String))
```

However, in order to compose this with `getResponseBody` we are required to use monadic combinators.  There are all sorts of math-y reasons for this, but for simplicity's sake just think of it as function composition not being powerful enough to compose actions together, only functions.  To compose actions, monads were introduced and they come with their own composition operators instead.  Compare the types of these two composition operators:

```
(.)   ::            (b ->   c) -> (a ->   b) -> (a ->   c)
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c)  -- Imported from Control.Monad
```

They're very similar, aren't they?  The only difference is the addition of the `m` with the `Monad` constraint.  This is **the** composition operator for monads, it is more restrictive and powerful than the normal `.` operator, which means it can do more, such as sequencing and executing IO actions, but it also means that it works with fewer types.  It can be used as

```
get = simpleHTTP <=< simpleHTTP . getRequest
```

However, there is a more generalized version of composition defined in `Control.Category` that can handle both:

```
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)  -- Hide the less general versions in Prelude
import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow

get = runKleisli (Kleisli getResponseBody . Kleisli simpleHTTP) . getRequest
```

But this requires that you wrap your monadic functions in the `Kleisli` newtype wrapper and unwrap it with `runKleisli`.  You can also skip `Control.Category` and just use `Control.Arrow`:

```
get = runKleisli (Kleisli getResponseBody <<< Kleisli simpleHTTP) <<< getRequest
```

You can even swap this around to be

```
get = getRequest >>> runKleisli (Kleisli simpleHTTP >>> Kleisli getResponseBody)
```

if you want it to read left-to-right instead of right-to-left.

In the end, there are several ways to write equivalent code, but the most familiar and readable to most people, if you are adamant on pointfree style (it isn't necessary to be idiomatic), would be to use the usual `.` and `<=<` since it is the shortest implementation and uses more recognizable operators.  `Control.Category` and `Control.Arrow` are very useful when building something custom, but for the built-in types there are usually already operators defined that make more sense.

Comment: Thanks! So `>>=` is a compose operator for monadic functions. Are there any good examples of creating monads? From what I've seen: a monad describes a set of rules a type should follow. And it seems to me that Monad is more like a design pattern.